# Can a lapel / lavalier mic be attached to a boom or mic stand?

Tags: lavalier, lapel, boom

I'm in a situation where the client does not want the interruption of changing lapel mics for different speakers at a podium-audience style event.

We could get a 'reporter mic' but then we'd be limited on our applications for when we need a lapel mic.

We were also told a wireless 'reporter mic' would cut in and out if there is wifi nearby. That creates a huge limitation for us. We need wifi at the event and for potential live streaming.

I'm wondering: can a wireless lapel mic be attached to a boom or microphone stand, so that it acts like a 'regular' or 'condenser' mic (if you know what I mean)?

I worry if we just tape it to the podium, it won't pick up the sound very well.

I have been searching for clip-ons or attachments to make this work but don't see any online. Has anyone tried this? Or does anyone know what would happen if we tried this method? Any potential setbacks one can foresee?

Are there products out there for this? Or would we have to resort to good old-fashioned tape and rubber bands?

Comment: “…the interruption of changing lapel mics for different speakers” — are you assuming that only one mic will be available? Could this be solved by using two mics alternately? While one is in use on stage, the other (muted) can be transferred from the previous speaker to the following one, taking as long as needed without interrupting anything.

Comment: "We were also told a wireless 'reporter mic' would cut in and out if there is wifi nearby." is nonsense. Sorry, but whoever told you that is not in full control of their faculties.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create a problem? Get a wireless podium mic instead. Examples at the low cost end includes "Shure BLX24/PG58" (included as search example, not as specific equipment advice). These do not send on Wifi frequencys. There are professional level systems with even more resiliance and ruggedness -- hire these instead.  Then get lapel mics for the people that stay the same -- connect to a mixer. Done.

Or even better, use a wired mic at the podium, I like the Shure SM58 type of mics. You will need a sound mixer anyway in order to control volume and maybe switch between different input sources (perhaps the speakers want to show video clips on their computer).

Answer (score 1):

A 'wireless' lav mic is wired to its transmitter, so you'd still have a couple of metres of cable to deal with - otherwise, sure, you can tape a lav mic to a stand, or buy a specific gooseneck. I actually put one on a skinny gooseneck to be able to squeeze in tight to a drum kit. Your punters might not realise there's a mic there, though, it being so small. https://www.dpamicrophones.com/accessories/gooseneck-mount-for-4060-series-lavalier-microphone

[image]

Of course, by the time you've gone to the trouble of wiring it down the mic stand, you may as well wire it all the way & save on a transmitter.